# In Angular 13 why does my route subscription stop it hits a route without a param?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need a way to update a variable in my header component (always displayed) whenever a param changes in the URL.

My routing:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
         component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard/:id',
        component: DashboardComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home'}
];
```

The dashboard component has an ID attached to it and this is what I need to track. In the event a user goes to a page without an ID (such as the home route) I want the ID to show as 0.

I have this working to where it will track the ID as long as they continue to hit routes with an ID but as soon as they navigate to home all tracking is stopped.

**header.component**

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ClassToggleService, HeaderComponent } from '@coreui/angular-pro';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';  

@Component({
  selector: 'app-default-header',
  templateUrl: './default-header.component.html',
})
export class DefaultHeaderComponent extends HeaderComponent {

  private issuer: Subscription;

  constructor(private classToggler: ClassToggleService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    super();
  }

  issuerID: number;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.children.forEach(child => {
      child.params.subscribe(params => {
          const id = params['id'] || 0
          console.log('id ' + id)
          this.issuerID = id
      })
    })
  }
  
     //To prevent memory leak
     ngOnDestroy(): void {
      if (this.issuer)
        this.issuer.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does simply subscribing to route.params not work?

Comment: I have tried that as well and it never fires in my console.

Comment: Rethinking about this, I think your best approach is to have DashboardComponent register its current `id` parameter in a service. You can then subscribe to that in your header.

Comment: try add a path like `{path: 'dashboard',component: DashboardComponent,}` or some like `{path: 'dashboard/new',component: DashboardComponent,}` **after** of the `path: 'dashboard/:id'` -well, really not show the "0" and you need control the "id"- but should be work